# How do I re-write URLs with htaccess in a WAMP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Could someone please tell what I am doing wrong. I have searched through lots of posts here and elsewhere about doing this.

Just want to make localhost/index.php?page=somepage look like localhost/somepage

Here is what I have so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 
</IfModule>
```

Not getting any errors, but it's not dong anything actually. Maybe I have the code right but just can't do this on my system. But would like a pro opinion.

Thank you.

Maybe worth mentioning: have htaccess file in root dir, all pages are in a folder named "pages" and all end in .htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like it takes a request like: `localhost/somepage` and internally rewrites it to `localhost/index.php?page=somepage`, which is really what you want. But it doesn't address if someone tries to go to `localhost/index.php?page=somepage`. In order to address that, you don't want to rewrite URL's, you want to *redirect the browser to a **new** URL*:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?page=([^\ \&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: Ok, I replaced my cond & rule with what you sugested and now I get browser error "This webpage has a redirect loop" But, the URL looks right: "root/page" So, were half way their. LOL Idealy I want a user to type mysite.com/page to get to the page they want. And it does work that way before I added the new htaccess stuff but the final URL is mysite.com/index.php?page=thepage Thanks :) I forgot to mention I also have DirectoryIndex index.php as the first line of my    htaccess and Redirect /about/ http://localhost/index.php?page=about for each page.

Comment: @RustyShackleford make sure to add it *before* the rule that you have, also, you should probably include a `[L]` flag at the end of your rule.

Comment: Ok, this is my new code: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?page=([^\ \&]+)
 RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]` I no longer get the error and can view the page I want to view but URL back to beggining. :(

Comment: @RustyShackleford dunn owhy your URL is changing, since there is nothing in the rules that redirect it back, you are also missing the conditions for the rule that routes to `index.php`

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting "Internal Server Error"

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache Server at mysite Port 80